# Cómo concatenar variables en C++

Tags: c++

He estado como loco buscando como puedo concatenar dos variables, pongo como ejemplo una cadena de python:

```
print ("("+str(a)+", "+str(b)+")")
```

Quisiera hacer lo mismo pero en C++, no he encontrado como, de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 15):

#### Python contra C++

Python y C++ son lenguajes bastante diferentes, el primero es interpretado y el segundo compilado; el primero tiene tipado dinámico y el segundo estático, esto hace que algunas instrucciones se interpreten de manera muy diferente en ambos lenguajes, en la instrucción que pones de ejemplo:

```
"("+str(a)+", "+str(b)+")"
```

Tienes tres objetos de texto (`"("`, `", "`, `")"`) que en Python son tratados como [objetos de secuencia de texto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) y en C++ son tratados como un arreglo de caracteres finalizado con caracter nulo (`\0`) conocido como [literal de texto](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Estás usando también la [función de conversión a texto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) de Python para transformar las variables `a` y `b` a un texto para que pueda ser concatenado con `+`. El equivalente de C++ sería [`std::to_string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) que funciona con casi todos los tipos numéricos existentes.

#### C++

Sin saber los tipos de `a` y de `b`, es difícil hablar de concatenar variables. Si ambas son de tipo [`std::string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string), la concatenación es automática mediante el operador libre de concatenado [`operator+`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B), dando lugar a el siguiente código:

```
std::string resultado = "(" + a + ", " +  b + ")"; // concatenar
std::cout << resultado << '\n'; // mostrar
```

Si `a` y de `b` fuesen de [tipo numérico](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) antes del concatenado deberías convertirlos a cadena:

```
std::string resultado = "(" + std::to_string(a) + ", " +  std::to_string(b) + ")"; // concatenar
std::cout << resultado << '\n'; // mostrar
```

Independientemente del tipo, podrías mostrar directamente los valores por consola:

```
std::cout << "(" << a << ", " << b << ")" << '\n'; // mostrar directamente
```

El único requisito es que el [stream de consola](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) reconozca el tipo a mostrar, [cosa que ya sucede](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) con la mayoría de tipos habituales, pero si `a` y/o `b` son tipos personalizados también puedes personalizar el operador de inyección a stream ([`operator <<`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)) para que reconozca tu tipo.

De la misma familia que el stream de consola, tenemos el [stream de texto](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) que igualmente podrá aceptar datos con el operador de inyección (`operator <<`) independientemente del tipo de estos datos, luego podrá extraerse el texto resultante para ser mostrado:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "(" << a << ", " << b << ")"; // concatenar
std::cout << ss.str() << '\n'; // mostrar
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta es un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a = "Hola";
    string b = "Mundo";
    string c = a + " "+b;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres concatenar dos variables, independientemente del tipo, `stringstream`, es la manera más fácil:

```
int aux=1;
std::string auxString="saludos";
std::stringstream example;
example << aux << auxString << std::endl;
```

Para obtener el string del `stringstream` sólo usa `.str();`.

Answer (score 1):

Para concatener strings puedes utilizar esta sintaxis:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Calle, Numero, Colonia, Direccion;
    Calle = "Roble";
    Numero = "123";
    Colonia = "Los Pinos";
    Direccion = Calle + " " + Numero + ", " + Colonia;
    cout << Direccion << endl;
}
```

Output: `Roble 123, Los Pinos`

o también puedes utilizar la concatenación en la misma variable:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno;
    Nombre = "Pedro ";
    ApellidoPaterno = "Lopez ";
    ApellidoMaterno = "Perez";
    Nombre += ApellidoPaterno;
    Nombre += ApellidoMaterno;
    cout << Nombre << endl;
}
```

Output: `Pedro Lopez Perez`

Answer (score 1):

A la hora concatenar en una variable tipo string con varios elementos de un vector tipo string es mejor hacerlo mediante copia usando un vector char. Ya que los valores de los vectores se van a cargar en la variable con todo su valor aunque tenga una sola letra y no van a caber más de dos elementos, como mucho. En este ejemplo use un vector AnsiString:

```
char CResultados [50]=" ";
AnsiString CaResultados;

for(int h=0;h<10;h++){
    strcpy(CResultados, VequiposP[h][2].c_str()); //Lo pasamos al vector char.
    CaResultados = CaResultados + "(" + CResultados + ")"; //luego se lo sumamos.
}
```

Comment: A la hora de dar soluciones, si las mismas no hacen uso del estándar conviene indicarlo. En tu caso ese código únicamente podrá ser útil para gente que compile con Borland... no está de más indicarlo. Ten en cuenta que ese detalle limita la aplicabilidad de tu solución

Comment: Con esto no intento desilusionarte ni criticar tu respuesta, te lo comento para que lo tengas en cuenta en futuras respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Este modo para concatenar las variables es para el IDE de programación Qt en cualquier versión, te recomiendo este IDE si estas empezando en C++ a mi gusto es muy intuitivo y completo.

```
QString a = "Hola";
QString b = "¿Cómo estás?";
QString c = a + b;
qDebug() << c;
```

Si quieres concatenar una variable de texto con una de tipo int, float etc. debes usar la siguiente forma, ya que muchos de los objetos gráficos de este IDE no aceptan directamente los números en su contenido

```
QString a = "Hola";
int b = 15;
QString c = a + QString::number(b);
qDebug() << c;
```

Listo.

Comment: ¿Podrías describir por qué estás usando ese tipo en vez de `std::string`? ¿Crees que sería la respuesta directa a la pregunta, o una alternativa? Por favor, consideremos que quien lee esta pregunta puede estar iniciándose en el lenguaje. La idea del sitio es sumar respuestas con la mayor calidad posible, y no sólo un fragmento de código sin explicación alguna.

Comment: Perdón, El tipo de dato corresponde al IDE de programación Qt, lo puse por que al entrar aquí muchas veces veo que usan Qt para sus desarrollos y creo que fue mi error el generalizar esta idea a toda la comunidad.

Comment: está perfecto dar alternativas, pero no una respuesta que son 4 líneas de código sin ninguna explicación. Sería bueno si pudieses [edit] la respuesta explicando de qué se trata, cuando se usaría, etc... En fin, dando una respuesta de calidad (no lo que es actualmente sin describir nada)